# Concatenating a variable and load url using jQuery UI dialog

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I'm trying to pass a variable 'edit_id' to a load string but it doesn't seem to be working.

This isn't working:

```
$('#edit-page-dialog').load('includes/form_add_edit_page.inc.php?add-edit=edit&edit_id=' + edit_id).dialog({
```

Whereas adding the id into the string like this does work:

```
$('#edit-page-dialog').load('includes/form_add_edit_page.inc.php?add-edit=edit&edit_id=105').dialog({
```

This is how I'm setting the edit_id variable:

```
// edit-page dialog Link
$('.edit-page-link').click(function(){
    edit_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#edit-page-dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Is it at all possible?

Comment: I think `console.log(edit_id)` or `alert(edit_id)` would be the next logical step.

Comment: Define "isn't working". What _do_ you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the scope of the variable isn't correct.  `edit_id` is only used inside the function. Try declaring this variable outside the function and assigning the value then.

```
var  edit_id = 0;

// edit-page dialog Link
$('.edit-page-link').click(function(){
    edit_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#edit-page-dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

and then after this function use:

```
$('#edit-page-dialog').load('includes/form_add_edit_page.inc.php?add-edit=edit&edit_id=' + edit_id).dialog({ })
```

Comment: edit_id already has global scope. Declaring it outside the function is definitely best practice (no-one likes implied globals) but it's not the cause of the poster's problem.

Comment: Declaring the variable outside of the click function solved the problem.

Comment: Apologies for my comment above. Looking at the code at first glance it seemed that the variable was being initiated as a global already.

Comment: Yeah that's OK mate. We are all here to help and share knowledge with each other. Now I hope the person who voted me down also realise that :D

Comment: I'll gladly remove the downvote but you'll need to make an edit to the post. SO doesn't allow downvotes to be removed until a post is edited (which I think is kind of stupid)

Comment: Yeh I can understand the reason behind this.. anyways, post is edited, have fun.

Comment: @njreed: You can make a dummy edit, and you can always remove votes within five minutes of casting them. It's to persuade you to vote with care in the first place.